# Sourcetree and .gitignore: I don't find an explicitly ignored file name

Tags: filenames, gitignore, atlassian-sourcetree

I wanted to ignore a certain file for only its project's repository, and by accident I selected to add the ignore entry to the global ignore list.

My Sourcetree preferences says my `.gitignore_global` file is at path `/Users/myuser/.gitignore_global`. I go there and indeed I see the modification date of that file matches the time I selected to add the ignore entry, but when I open it, I don't see any explicit file name there.

So, how could I revert the change I made?

Answer (score 0):

Go the the folder where that file is ignore and type:

```
git check-ignore -v -- aFile
```

That will give you the exact location of the ignore file which is responsible for not tracking (ignoring) said file.